# Understanding proof of every continuous function to be Integrable

Tags: real-analysis

Standard proof in book says suppose a function $f(x)$ is continuous in $[a,b]$ , then divide $[a,b]$ into finite sub-intervals such that oscillation of $f(x)$ in each of these sub-intervals is < $\epsilon/(b-a)$

Then further calculating we get oscillatory sum, $w(P, f)$ < $\epsilon$ and since $\epsilon$ is any positive number hence $w(P, f) = 0$. Therefore, function is integrable.

I don't understand how can we assume oscillation of $f(x)$ in sub-intervals < $\epsilon/(b-a)$ . Isn't it possible that $\epsilon$  here is a large number and not close to $0$ ?

Comment: $\epsilon$ is an arbitrary positive number, so you can choose $\epsilon$ to be close to zero

Comment: How can we assume that  oscillation of f(x) in sub-intervals < ϵ/(b−a) ?

Comment: Do you know the theorem saying that a function is continuous on $[a,b]$ if and only if it is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$?

Comment: Okay, got it. I was missing the uniform continuity part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand how can we assume oscillation of 
>   $f(x)$ in sub-intervals $< \epsilon/(b−a)$. Isn't it possible that $\epsilon$ here is a large number and not close to $0$?

Sure, if we don't select small enough subintervals then the $\epsilon$ needed may be large, but if the function is continuous over that interval, then there will always be *some* finite value that suffices.   Further, the smaller the subintervals the smaller an $\epsilon$ there can be.   Or conversely, for any $\epsilon$ we can find a finite number of subintervals whose oscilation fit the criteria.